# Adding BSON document to list is extremely slow

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, batch-insert

```
for (int k = 1; k < list.Count(); k++)
        {
            List<BsonDocument> batch = new List<BsonDocument>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list[k].Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                var obj = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                obj.Add("Status", false);
                obj.Add("Headers", new BsonArray(list[0].ElementAt(0).ItemArray));
                List<string> formattedArray = new List<string>();
                for (int j = 0; j < list[k].ElementAt(i).ItemArray.Count(); j++)
                {
                    formattedArray.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list[k].ElementAt(i).ItemArray[j]));   
                }
                obj.Add("Values", new BsonArray(formattedArray.ToArray()));
                MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument BSONDoc = new BsonDocument(obj);
                batch.Add(BSONDoc);
            }
            Insert(batch);
            batch.Clear();
        }
```

> list.Count() = 121
>
> list[k].Count() = 10000
>
> list[k].ElementAt(i).ItemArray.Count() = 137

Comment: Not that I think this has anything to do with your speed issue, but I think it would be better to put statements like list.Count() result into a variable, and then pass the variable to the for loop, because right now you are evaluating Count() everytime on a loop iteration.

Comment: Thats a good point, but there is definitely something wrong with this code, or may be i am missing something which is causing delay.

Comment: Use a [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) to time different parts of the code separately so you can see which part is taking up all the time. I see you can either remove `batch.Clear();`, or leave it and instantiate `batch` outside the for loop.

Comment: Yes you are right, but its not making much of a difference, i am reading from an excel file, which contains 60k+ records, I have to insert them into mongo by making batches of 10k. Its taking alot of time to create a batch of 10k.

Comment: are you using Excels' interop assemblies to read rows from Excel file or some other toolkit?

Comment: TotalDays: 0.000042218967592592591
 TotalHours: 0.0010132552222222222
 TotalMilliseconds: 3647.7188
 TotalMinutes: 0.060795313333333337
 TotalSeconds: 3.6477188
Its taking this much of time for just making a batch of 500 records, and i need 6 batches of 10k records, and i feel its getting even more slower with the growing records.

Comment: I am using excel reader reference.

Comment: You said elsewhere that `batch.Add()` is taking most of the time, how much of the 3.65 seconds is `batch.Add()` taking?

Comment: batch.Add() is taking 
3.65 sec for 500records.
1min 26sec for 2500 records.
And its growing exponentially. Getting worse with more records.
I need 6 batches of 10k records, that would take ages.

Comment: One of bottleneck is Json.Net. This is the most popular Json serialize but not the fastest. You can significantly reduce serialization time by using a faster json lib (like jil or netjon in my benchmark). In addition move all list creation outside of loop (batch, formattedArray, obj [List<BsonElement> (with hashset for unicity) instead of Dictionnary]. And set their capacity in the constructor parameter.

Comment: Thanks Kalten for suggestions. I will implement them.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of suggestions from me.

1) Assign list[k].Count() into a variable outside the loop.

2) new BsonArray(list[0].ElementAt(0).ItemArray). You can get this once and assign it to headers. No need to go for multiple times.

3) Finally, Run the Benchmark (using stopwatch) to see sections that are more time  consuming.

Comment: I ran the stopwatch as mentioned in the above comment, and i already knew whats taking time,
batch.Add(BSONDoc); this is the culprit.

Comment: That's great you found it. So have you tried implementing solution using multiple threads and using concurrent collections. That's just an approach, you can see that possibility too if it fits in your case.

Comment: Yes i am doing with async task factory, its working soo fast, but i just need to know its taking that  much of time when using sync approach. I mean that is unacceptable. I tried it on PHP using sync approach and worked for me in 2-3 sec, all 60k records. But here it seems it would take more than an hour for 60k records.